# Is there a file size limit of the clover db at 2GB?

Tags: java, code-coverage, clover

We have 3 clover dbs, one for clienttests, integrationtests and unittests.

For calculating the total coverage, we merge those databases into a new clover db:
As you can see, this works as expected (and as it always did for over 18 months now)

```
[clover-merge] Clover Version 3.0.3, built on October 26 2010 (build-dev) 
[clover-merge] Loaded from: C:\devtools\clover-ant-3.0.2-patch101026\lib\clover.jar 
[clover-merge] Clover: Commercial License registered to ... 
[clover-merge] Merging database 1 of 3: d:\coverage\java\all\coverage/clienttests\coverage.db 
[clover-merge] Merging database 2 of 3: d:\coverage\java\all\coverage/integrationtests\coverage.db 
[clover-merge] Merging database 3 of 3: d:\coverage\java\all\coverage/junit\coverage.db 
[clover-merge] Writing merged database registry [clover-merge] Merge complete
```

Since last weekend i get the following problem when trying to generate reports from the merged coveragedb file:

```
[clover-report] Clover Version 3.0.3, built on October 26 2010 (build-dev) 
[clover-report] Loaded from: C:\devtools\clover-ant-3.0.2-patch101026\lib\clover.jar 
[clover-report] Clover: Commercial License registered to ... 
[clover-report] Loading coverage database from: 'd:\coverage\java\all\clover\cloverDB\coverage.db' 
[clover-report] Report generation failed: Clover encountered a problem reading the instrumentation registry "d:\coverage\java\all\clover\cloverDB\coverage.db". This database may have been corrupted. Please regenerate.
```

I checked the file and noticed, that its size is (according to windows explorer): 2,08 GB (2.244.583.202 bytes), which is just over 2GB.
I do not know the sizes of the previous weekends run, since we do not keep the coverage dbs,
but since nothing else changed in the procedure, i assume that 2GB is the problem here.

Comment: The coverage data is actually 2Gb?? How big is the software system being tested (SLOC)?  I'd expect it to be several hundred million bytes worst case if you had 100 million lines of code, based on raw information demand (not on any specific knowledge of clover). What's in there besides raw coverage information?

Comment: @Anthony: I tried accessing the 3 cloverdb databases before merging, which works, then i tried accessing the merged one, which did not work anymore.  The file resulting from merging the 3 files actually IS just over 2 GB large.

Comment: @Ira: The project i run coverage on is around 1Mio lines of code. I have per-test coverage turned on (we need that), and this does not result from a single testrun, but from 60-80 runs. Those are client tests, integration tests and unit tests, and they are run on multiple platforms with different setups on each run. The size has always been in the range around that and was continously growing. Now it hit 2GB.

Comment: @Ron: And your purpose in doing the combination is to see overall test coverage, regardless of which set of tests?

Comment: Exactly. We also do reports on the specific databases, but we also want to be able to see overall tes tcoverage (which worked well for the last 18 months or so).

Comment: @Ron: so it appears you hit an implementation limit on Clover (somebody is using an INT somewhere, and it overflowed).  Even if that gets fixed (you are on commercial support, right?) the time to combine all this information into a 2GB file must not be fun.  There are other tools that can give the test coverage data and arbitrary summary combinations without running into this wall (by virtue of using smaller files to represent the same data).  Is clover's file format some kind of XML (that would explain the gigantic size relative to your problem)?

Comment: I already opened an issue at atlassian. I just wanted to see if there is already a solution out there. Thank you anyway, i will post the results if i get them. But currently it looks like an integer overflow in the file format.

Comment: Are you interested in a different test coverage tool that doesn't havve the problem?

Comment: You wrote "the size ... was continuously growing". Do you delete Clover databases between builds ? This can be a reason of the growth. I'm asking because there's no need to keep them. It's enough to keep test optimization snapshots (in case you use Clover's test optimization) and history snapshots (in case you generate historical reports). ... Unless you perform incremental builds instead of builds from a clean workspace.